# Does a "Hello" screen mean my iPhone was erased?

Tags: iphone, secure-erase

I'm preparing to ship my old iPhone 6 to a new home. When I press and hold the lock button, a white screen saying "Hello" in various languages appears. Does that mean I erased all of my data? I haven't used the phone in months so I can't remember what I did to get the phone to that screen, but I want to be sure that my data is erased before getting rid of the device.

**TL;DR** Is it possible to get an iPhone to the white "Hello" set up screen without completely erasing the previous user's data?

Answer (score 3):

The "Hello" screen does not *necessarily* mean you have erased the phone. It could just mean that iOS was updated. I would complete the setup steps (you can skip many of them) then go into Settings > General > Reset > *Erase All Content and Settings* to be sure. You will also need to remove the device from your iCloud account or it will be bricked to the new owner.

Comment: If the page after the hello screen is to choose a language/region, it's very likely it was reset. However, because of how easy it is to re-wipe it I would agree with this solution.

Comment: @EzekielElin From what I remember, it asked to choose a language, insert an active SIM card without a SIM lock, and connect to a Wifi network and/or iTunes. I would have skipped the setup steps and done the erasure option again if I could, but I couldn't figure out how to do that without re-enabling the cell service using my SIM card (something I didn't want to do).

Comment: @Posdari I would consider that properly erased